# How to play sound through an eclipse rap/rwt application so it plays through the web browser

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, audio, eclipse-rap

Does anyone know how to play sound/audio through eclipse RWT application? RWT application is viewed through a browser and I want play the sound on the browser. I can play sound using Javascript, but this is outside RWT application. I could not find any API to play sound either. So, what is the solution? Thanks.
JM

I could not find any method to play the sound through RWT so it plays through the web browser. I can play sound on the server, but that is not what I want.